# Why does an undefined operand not return false?

Tags: javascript

Given the following:

```
let a;
let b = false;
let c = a && b === undefined;
```

In my understanding, `undefined` is a falsy value, so why is it that `c` has value `undefined` instead of `false`?

Comment: It's actually a short circuit in `a && whatever`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: What other value would you expect in `c`, `false`? But `c = undefined` is *falsy* already.

Comment: Because that's how JS works: you declared, but not initialized, the variable `a` so as per the spec its value is `undefined`, and because `c = a` returns the value of the assignment, we're done. The `&& ....` part never runs because it can't change the result.

Comment: "why is it that c has value undefined" as opposed to what?

Comment: Ternary operator confusion tho not used. But worth investigating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your example, `a` is undefined. Therefore, `a && ...` is `undefined && ...`, and since undefined is falsy, [the left hand side short circuits](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation). That means, it never evaluates the right hand side.

If the left hand side is falsy, there's nothing the right-hand side of an `&&` can do to change that. To use an analogy, `false && anything` always evaluates to `false`, and in JavaScript, it stops there and ignores `anything`.

Now, the question may be, "Why doesn't it return `false` instead of `undefined`?" [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy#the_logical_and_operator):

> ### The logical AND operator, &&
>
> If the first object is falsy, it returns that object
>
> ```
> false && "dog" // ↪ false
>
> 0 && "dog" // ↪ 0
> ```

Comment: This does need a link to the docs that explain that, so that folks can continue their journey there. Just saying it short circuits doesn't make it true =)

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I was about to make the same edit :)

Comment: Seems to me if "falsy" happens in expression *ever* on &&, result should be false too, to "short circuit". Bug in JS discovered.

Comment: there is no bug? `a` is `undefined` as per the spec. `undefined` is falsy, and `false && anything` short circuits, so `c = a && ....` becomes `c = a` and `c` is assigned the value `undefined`.

Comment: "If the first object is falsy, it returns that object" - now that explains it all in 10 words.

Comment: @mardubbles I wouldn't call it a bug since it is defined and intentional, but personally, I don't like it; it's really confusing when a function returns `0` (for example) and your code goes down an unexpected path. This is why I prefer `if (x === true/false/undefined/0/etc.)` over `if(x)` when I am writing JavaScript. On the other hand, leveraging falsy and && can make code more concise in some situations.

Comment: @DanielKaplan I prefer explict on extra equals for coding as well. I rarely do `let x`; I do `let x = false` then on explicitly equality of extra conditions on false. But thats just me. It's always interesting to see how verbose and powerful javascript is.

Answer (score 2):

`c` ends up `undefined` because `a` is `undefined`. The `&&` operator stops with the first value that's falsy through a process called [short circuiting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: It never gets to `b === undefined` as the result of assignment is falsy so the `&&` returns `undefined` not `false`.

Comment: "The && operator stops with the first value that's falsy." - I understand that it stops with the first falsely value, but shouldn't it return false? I read it like this: "c is true if (a is truthy AND b is undefined)". Since a is not truthy, the answer is that c must be false.

Comment: then you understand it incorrectly. `let c = a && b === undefined` tries to assign `a && b === undefined` to `c`. So, let's do that: `a` is undefined as per the spec, and whatever follows is completely irrelevant because `undefined` is falsy, and `false && anything` is still false. As such (given [short circuiting for logical operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)) JS does not bother with the rest: it _stops_ once it sees that `a` is undefined and assigns `c` the value of `a`, being `undefined`.

Comment: But wait, && logic from left to right, does not look at "but === does not perform any type coercion", when left operator was falsy? Scratching head...

Comment: Ah, I think I got it, I wasn't aware of that pattern, I can't believe this is the first time I came across this.

Comment: that's a fair point: @Pointy the first paragraph really contributes nothing here. The reason we're getting undefined is because of short circuiting. It has nothing to do with `==` vs `===`.

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I upvoted for being the fastest answer, but accepted DanielKaplan's answer because as Mike above says, the "If the first object is falsy, it returns that object" really hits the nail.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well "contributes nothing" may be a bit of an overstatement, because even though it wasn't the crux of the issue the `===` comparison was incorrect; it's not clear to me why it was even there of course, but the OP should probably know that it won't work, and that it has nothing to do with "falsyness".

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was my fault, I had to rephrase the question 2 times to make it clearer, see edits. And I wasn't even aware until your comment now that "the === comparison was incorrect", but that's a good point too that I see now.